# How to add thirld column in DbModelBuilder using entityframework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

I tried to add new bool field in a table with code first approach but it's doesn't work 
please have a that is my code which i used.

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<CollegeActivity>()
            .HasMany<ApplicationRole>(s => s.ApplicationRoles)
            .WithMany(c => c.Activities)
            .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("ActivityId");
                cs.MapRightKey("RoleId");
                cs.MapRightKey("IsInternal");
                cs.ToTable("ActivityRoleRelationship");
            });
```

Table Name : ActivityRoleRelationship

and this new bool column which i tried to add but it's not added

```
cs.MapRightKey("IsInternal");
```

Can you please help me what i'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

That's no how you add a new column to a table.

You need to use Migration. First you need you need to add a `bool` property on your `ActivityRoleRelationship` class

```
public class ActivityRoleRelationship
{
    ***

    public bool IsInternal{ set; get; }
}
```

and then type these codes in Package Manager Console

`add-migration AddIsInternal`

`update-database`

check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) for more information about migration